# Issue with Modal View Controllers and definesPresentationContext

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios5

I've created a custom container view controller using the [new UIViewController container view controller methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) in iOS 5.

Trouble is, even though my container controller's child UIViewController has [`definesPresentationContext = YES`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/definesPresentationContext), when it [creates and presents another modal view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html), UIKit sets the container (rather than the child) as the presenting controller.

For example, in MyChildViewController.m:

```
- (void)showMailComposeView:(id)sender {

    __block MFMailComposeViewController *vc =
            [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    vc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    vc.subject = @"Subject";

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

       if ([self.modalViewController isEqual:vc])
            NSLog(@"This should print...");

       if ([vc.presentingViewController isEqual:self.parentViewController])
            NSLog(@"... but this shouldn't");

       // NOTE: Both log statements printed

    }];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError*)error
{ 
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

    // NOTE: self.parentViewController.view now displays instead of self.view
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

How do I ensure it's the *child* view which gets revealed when the modal view gets dismissed (rather than the container view)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this line before presenting the view controller:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext
```

If you've done all the correct parent-child things all the way up the view controller chain, this will cause the presented view to replace the MyChildViewController's view, and then the MyChildViewController's view will return when the presented view is dismissed.

Oh, and I forgot to mention, even then this will work only on iPad. A presented view controller's view always occupies the whole screen on iPhone - it is always presented from the root view.

**EDIT:** Starting in iOS 8, this feature is also available on iPhone. (And so are popovers and split views - basically, most statements of the form "only on iPad" became false with iOS 8, which in my view is awesome news.)

Comment: While my question/problem was a little different, this worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Interesting as to why on an iPhone, modal is always from the root view. I have a similar container situation on iPhone and doing all of the above, I was wondering why the modal view wasn't getting presented from within the bounds of the child view controller's view. It sounds like this is just an iPhone behavior that is different than iPad.

Comment: so... no modal in a uiviewcontroller container on iPhone?

Comment: @DamienRomito Correct. Look at my example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch06p270modalPresentationContext/ch19p607modalPresentationContext It experiments with this feature by doing a modal presentation inside a view controller inside a tab bar controller. It works on iPad but not on iPhone. - However, in iOS 7 you can do a custom modal transition, which sort of makes up for this by letting you make a small presented view on top of the existing interface.

Comment: Thank you @matt, I've just did a custom transition with a traditional UIView animation.

Comment: @Damien Yes, that can be a perfectly good solution. Another possibility is a custom container controller; I've got another example where I use that to "flip" one view to replace another: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p316containerController/ch19p631containerController/ViewController.m

Comment: @Damien The advantage (if that's what it is) is that now you're using a view controller's view to replace another view controller's view. You mustn't do that if you are _merely_ doing a UIView transition animation, but you can do it if it is all done through a custom parent view controller.

Comment: Looks like, at least as of iOS 8, this approach *does* work on iPhones.

Comment: @JeffKelley Yes, that's well known (and important!). I'll edit to add that - thanks for pointing this out.