# iPhone, iOS 8: How to presentViewController smaller than original view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have two view controllers, I want to present view controller(VC) of the first VC. Second VC have smaller size. I want to show second view controller over the first one. Like a popover. You can imagine it, if we add another view controller that slides from bottom to top but stops at navigation bar.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func showSecondVC(sender: AnyObject) {
            
    let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    
    secondViewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: header.frame.height), size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - header.frame.height))

    secondViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
    secondViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    
    secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
           
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)


}
```

You can see that I set frame for `secondViewController`. I want that it will be with this frame, but if I add completion block and show it's frame after animation, it will be same as first View Controller have.

## Edit

I also want to mention, that I try to make this in Portrait orientation.

Comment: I made a Github repo [BonsaiController](https://github.com/rishi420/Bonsai) just for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you try this in iPhone, the built-in root view of presented view controller will **always be full screen**, so your efforts to resize it will not be successful. (iPad is a different story)

Just let the root view as it is (i.e. don't fight the fact it's full screen size ), but make its background color **clear color**. If you want to present some kind of customised view/content/whatever it is..for example a smaller view with some warning..or some options. Just add it as a subview of the root view.

UPDATE:
As the UIViewController class documentation says:

"In a horizontally compact environment, the presented view is always full screen."

The only combination I can imagine for this to work is Iphone6+ in landscape mode where the horizontal size class is then larger then compact. So you are out of luck because you want portrait.

Comment: as I read, this behaviour is available in iOS 8, read @matt answer edit or comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923927/issue-with-modal-view-controllers-and-definespresentationcontext

Comment: EarlGrey, I'm sorry, I don't get your answer. 
The full phrase from docs: "In a horizontally compact environment, the presented view is always full screen. In a horizontally regular environment, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.", but what if we don't talk about class sizes, for now I don't use size class at all, so I have Any width Any height. I see here remark about `horizontally compact` and `horizontally regular` what about else cases?

Comment: any iPhone in portrait mode is horizontal compact. In horizontal compact, the first sentence applies. The classification of form factors to size classes is chosen by apple. You have no other choice but to respect it.

Comment: I see, what can you propose as alternative?

Comment: See my 2nd paragraph in my answer, it really is an straightforward and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

To add the Earl Grey's response, after setting the ViewController's background color to clear. Create a segue with the following properties set:

- *Kind* to "Present Modally"
- *Presentation* to "Over Current Context"